# Not able to render a simple ReactDOM div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a newbie to ReactJS. I was trying yo render a simple div using ReactDOM but not able to do so. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script>
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
          document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody guide me as to why its happening ?

**Note** - I am using React 15.4.2 and Chrome version 57.

Comment: What is the error message?  Probably, you can't use JSX without babel.

Comment: pretty sure you need to specify the script type for inlined React `<script type="text/babel">...` and need something to transpile like babel. Are you following some specific tutorial? There's heaps online just google for them. Also when you post it's good to let us know what errors you're getting and what you've tried. Is there nothing on the page at all? Are there any errors in the console? etc.

Comment: @Jayce444 I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` exception in console.

Comment: If you're new to React, you'd be far better off using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/) - it handles this kind of thing out of the box.

Comment: I am using [create-react-app|https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/] to learn ReactJS, but I have to use ReactJS in my existing application for which I cannot structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the transpiler babel to your project. you can adapt my example below to your needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

see another example that doesn't use babel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('h1', null, 'hello'), document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @EnogweVictor, it worked ! But how can I replace an in-browser Babel transformer so that I can precompile the scripts ?

Comment: Browsers don't understand JSX, if you want to precomplie your project scripts say transforming from es6 to es5, plus browser compatible JSX without needing babel in the browser, you can checkout babel packages on npm using nodeJs( see an example github project using this  at github.com/andela-venogwe/docman) or see this link https://babeljs.io/repl/ to convert your jsx react code to browser readable format.  I've added another example to my previous answer that doesn't use babel but uses a transformed browser compatible version of the previous ReactDOM.render implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use JSX without any transpiler (babel etc).

Try this instead:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement('hi', 'Hello, world!'),
          document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

Or add a script and `type` to handle JSX.